# Preserve and print a blog

Tags: blog, blogger, backups

When my daughter was born almost 5 years ago, we had the idea of posting various things about our lives, what she did as she was growing up, etc.  The idea at the time was, when she's 18 we'll give her a link to the site and let her browse.  My concern is that a lot can change in the next 13 years, and perhaps the website\pictures just wont be available in the same manner we envisioned it.  Or even worse.. if I die.. I want my daughter to be able to find the notes on this stuff =]

TL;DR:
So I have a blogger.com hosted blog.  If I wanted to take the past 5 years worth of posts and "preserve" it in a readable fashion, can I get it printed somehow? How can I archive my site?  I do periodically download the ATOM XML feed and images, but I'd like to have something preserved that we can still read and hand over at some point.

Comment: The sentence *Is there a different archival service I can use?* is asking for a recommendation which is off-topic here. However, you can simply ask *How can I archive this site?* would be enough of a change to keep it from being placed on-hold. This is a good question in that there are times that a demo of a site is required and being able to mimic a site on a CD, for example, would be a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are satisfied with a digital copy, you can 'scrape' the entire site using a tool like [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/). It will download the entire website, saving each page locally. That means you could continue browsing the site when off-line, or after Google shuts down Blogger.

One thing to note is that images and other page assets will be saved by HTTrack, but say for example you had a blog post with an embedded YouTube video - that video would not be saved. Since you asked about printing I trust this is acceptable? If not, [Google have a 'Data Liberation' team](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3024190) who make it possible to export your data from their services.

You can also manually print each blog post (or even 'print to PDF') but this is tedious. If you want to pay someone else to do it you can try one of the various [print to book services](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=blogger%20print%20to%20book&t=canonical) who will scrape your site for you and produce a proper hardcover book.

Comment: Thanks @TomBrossman, those are some great ideas, +5 bonus points for linking via duckduckgo!